# Switch from Modelling a Process using a Poisson Distribution to use a Negative Binomial Distribution?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, kalman-filter, poisson-process, state-space-models

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$We have a random process that may-or-may-not occur multiple times in a set period of time $T$. We have a data feed from a pre-existing model of this process, that provides the probability of a number of events occurring in the period $0 \leq t < T$. This existing model is old and we need to run live checks on the feed-data for estimation errors. The old model producing the data-feed (which is providing the probability of $n$ events occurring in the time-remaining $t$) is approximately Poisson Distributed.

So to check for anomalies/errors, we let $t$ be the time remaining and $X_t$ be the total number of events to occur in the remaining time $t$. The old model implies the estimates $\P(X_t \leq c)$. So under our assumption $X_t\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_{t})$ we have:
$$
\P(X_t \leq c) = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^c\frac{\lambda_t^k}{k!}\,.
$$
To derive our event rate $\lambda_t$ from the output of old model (observations $y_{t}$), we use a state space approach and model the state relationship as:
$$
y_t = \lambda_t + \varepsilon_t\quad (\varepsilon_t \sim N(0, H_t))\,.
$$
We filter the observations from the old model, using a state space [constant speed decay] model for the evolution of the $\lambda_t$ to obtain the filtered state $E(\lambda_t|Y_t)$ and flag an anomaly/error in the estimated event frequency from the the feed-data if $E(\lambda_t|Y_t) < y_t$.

This approach works fantastically well at picking up errors in the estimated event counts over the full time-period $T$, but not so well if we want to do the same for another period $0 \leq t < \sigma$ where $\sigma < \frac{2}{3} T$. To get around this, we have decided we now want to switch to use the Negative Binomial distribution so that we assume now $X_t\sim NB(r, p)$ and we have: 
$$
    \P(X_{t} \leq c) = p^{r}\sum_{k = 0}^c (1 - p)^{k}\binom{k + r -1}{r - 1},
$$
where the parameter $\lambda$ is now replaced by $r$ and $p$. This should be straightforward to implement, but I am having some difficulties with interpretation and thus I have some questions I'd like you to help with:

**1.** Can we merely set $p = \lambda$ in the negative binomial distribution? If not, why not?

**2.** Assuming we can set $p = f(\lambda)$ where $f$ is some function, how can we correctly set $r$ (do we need to fit $r$ using past data sets)?

**3.** Is $r$ dependent on the number of events we expect to occur during a given process?

---

*Addendum to extracting estimates for $r$ (and $p$):*

I am aware that if we in fact had this problem reversed, and we had the event counts for each process, we could adopt the maximum likelihood estimator for $r$ and $p$. Of course the maximum likelihood estimator only exists for samples for which the sample variance is larger than the sample mean, but if this was the case we could set the likelihood function for $N$ independent identically distributed observations $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_{N}$ as:
$$
    L(r, p) = \prod_{i = 1}^{N}\P(k_i; r, p),
$$
from which we can write the log-likelihood function as: 
$$
l(r, p) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \ln(\Gamma(k_i + r)) - \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \ln(k_{i}!) - N\ln(\Gamma(r)) + \sum_{i = 1}^{N} k_i \ln(p) + N r\ln(1 - p).
$$
To find the maximum we take the partial derivatives with respect to $r$ and $p$ and set them equal to zero:
\begin{align*}
    \partial_{r} l(r, p) &= \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \psi(k_i + r) - N\psi(r) + N\ln(1 - p), \\
    \partial_{p} l(r, p) &= \sum_{i = 1}^{N} k_i\frac{1}{p} - N r \frac{1}{1 - p} \enspace .
\end{align*}
Setting $\partial_{r} l(r, p) = \partial_{p} l(r, p) = 0$ and setting $p = \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \displaystyle\frac{k_i} {(N r + \sum_{i = 1}^{N} k_i)},$ we find: 
$$
    \partial_{r} l(r, p) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \psi(k_i + r) - N \psi(r) + N\ln\left(\frac{r}{r + \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \frac{k_i}{N}}\right) = 0.
$$
This equation cannot be solved for r in closed form using Newton or even EM. However, this is not the case in this situation. Although we *could* use the past data to get a static $r$ and $p$ this is not really any use as for our process, we need to adapt these parameters in time, like we did using Poisson.

Comment: Why not just plug your data into a Poisson or Negative Binomial regression model?

Comment: I don't feel it should _have_ to be used. Bearing in mind that Poisson is the limiting case of Negative Binomial, there should be some way to parameterize this problem in a similar way I have done for Poisson. In addition, this process occurs simultaneously for thousands of difference processes and not one has the same "event rate", meaning regression analysis for these parameters would have to be done at every new observation for all live processes. This is not feasible. Thanks very much for taking time to read my question and comment, it is most appreciated...

Comment: In terms of linking poisson to NB, if you have $(X_t|\lambda_t,r_t,g_t)\sim Pois (\lambda_tg_t) $ with hidden over dispersion variable $(g_t|r_t)\sim Gamma (r_t,r_t) $ so that $E (g_t)=1$ and $var(g_t)=r_t^{-1} $.  This will give a marginal NB distribution upon integrating out $g_t $.  You could use this to help.

Comment: That is a great help, but are you able to flesh this out a bit more and provide some explicit details? Thanks very much for your time...

Comment: Just a quick question, is $y_t $ an observed value of $X_t $?

Comment: $X_{t}$ is the total number of event that occur in the remaining time $t$. $y_{t}$ is the probability of those event _actually_ occurring in the remaining time $t$.

Comment: @StatsStudent I am now looking at regression modelling. How can I parameterize my model based on what I have described above? Perhaps I should ask another question...

Comment: @Killercam, yes, it's probably a good idea to ask another question.  You can refer to this one in the new question.  Be sure to clarify what exactly you mean by "parameterize" your model.  As a statistician, parameterize means something very specific to me and I'm wondering if you are using this word differently than how it's generally used in statistics.

Comment: What about using the binomial rather than the negative binomial? That may be easier to do. Anscombe FJ. The transformation of Poisson, binomial and negative-binomial data. Biometrika. 1948;35:246-54.

Answer (score 1):

The negative binomial distribution is very much similar to the binomial probability model. it is applicable when the following assumptions(conditions) hold good
1)Any experiment is performed under the same conditions till a fixed number of successes, say C, is achieved
2)The result of each experiment can be classified into one of the two categories, success or failure
3)The probability P of success is the same for each experiment
40Each experiment is independent of all the other. The first condition is the only key differentiating factor between binomial and negative binomial

Answer (score 0):

The poisson distribution can be a reasonable approximation of the binomial under certain conditions like
1)The probability of success for each trial is very small. P-->0
2)np=m(say) is finete
The rule most often used by statisticians is that the poisson is a good approximation of the binomial when n is equal to or greater than 20 and p is equal or less than 5%